# Can not test app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

Whenever I try to run my app on the iPhone it crashes **after** I  press a button or tab bar. I get the following error: `error: failed to launch -- failed to get the task for process 334` I tried creating a new distribution certificate but it does  not work.

This all works in the simulator.

---

Thanks, 
Abdullah Shafique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is because you are trying to debug your application using
>   distribution provisioning profile. If you want to run your application
>   in debug mode, you have to sign it with development provisioning
>   profile and certificate (both in build settings and in target). If you
>   are trying to create a distributable, sign it with distribution
>   credentials and add Entitlements.plist (again both in build settings
>   and target).

You have to select Development provisioning profile for every target.

Go into your Target => Build Settings => Code Signing => Code Signing Identity => select all for your development provisioning profile

In Xcode 5 , after your downloaded and added your developer provisioning profile, first select your Provisioning Profile: Target => Build Settings => Code Signing => Provisioning Profile => select all for your development provisioning profile

After this you can select your Code Signing Identity => select all for your development provisioning profile